# Pointer in function getting "must be modifiable lvalue" error

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a little issue - For some reason when I try to reallocate memory to a pointer to pointer of a struct to increase the amount of memory blocks by one for an extra struct in a function, Intellisense tells me that the "expression must be a modifiable lvalue". Thing is, if I try to allocate to the `input` itself, all is fine - the problem is when I try to reallocate to `input + 1`.

The structs in use:

```
struct Entry_t
{
    char *word;
    Year **years;
    char **syn;
    Meaning **mean;
    Entry *next;
};

struct Mean_t
{
    char *word;
    Entry **enword;
    Meaning *next;
};
```

The functions:

```
/*
| Function: IsInMean
| Action: Checks whether the meaning already exists
| Input: Master meaning struct, the string
| Returns: The address of the necessary place if yes, NULL otherwise
*/
Meaning *IsInMean(Meaning *MEANS, char *str)
{
    if(MEANS)
    {
        if(strcmp(MEANS->word,str) == 0)
            return MEANS;
        else
            return IsInMean(MEANS + 1,str);
    }
    else
        return MEANS;
}

/*
| Function: FindMeanPlace
| Action: Checks where to wedge the meaning.
| Input: The master Meanings dictionary, the string
| Returns: The address of the place where to wedge, NULL if all are bigger.
*/
Meaning *FindMeanPlace(Meaning *MEANS, char *str)
{
    int cmp;
    if((cmp = strcmp(MEANS->word,str)) > 0)
        return NULL;
    else if(cmp < 0 && strcmp(MEANS->next->word,str) > 0)
        return MEANS;
    else
        return FindMeanPlace(MEANS + 1,str);
}

/*
| Function: NewMean
| Action: Creates and initializes a new meaning struct
| and places in it a new entry
| Input: Standard input, new entry, string with the meaning
| Returns: The address of the new meaning struct
*/
Meaning *NewMean(STANDARD_INPUT,Entry *new_e, char *str)
{
    Meaning *temp = (Meaning*)malloc(sizeof(Meaning));
    InitMean(temp);
    temp->word = (char*)calloc(strlen(str) + 1,sizeof(char));
    strcpy(temp->word,str);
    *(temp->enword) = new_e;
    return temp;
}

/*
| Function: SetMean
| Action: Sets the meanings field of an entry
| Input: Standard input, address of the new entry and
| the appropriate sub-string
| Returns: nada
*/
void SetMean(STANDARD_INPUT, Entry *new_e, char *str)
{
    char *cutout, delim[] = ",_";
    char **temp = NULL;
    int len = 0, cmp, index;
    Entry **entemp, *etemp;
    Meaning *input, *mtemp;
    cutout = strtok(str,delim);
    while(cutout)
    {
        temp = (char**)realloc(temp,(len + 1)*sizeof(char*));
        if(!temp)
            Pexit(STANDARD_C);
        *temp = (char*)calloc(strlen(cutout) + 1,sizeof(char));
        if(!(*temp))
            Pexit(STANDARD_C);
        strcpy(*temp,cutout);
        temp++;
        len++;
        cutout = strtok(NULL,delim);
    }
    QsortCust(STANDARD_C,temp,len + 1);
    while(temp)
    {
        index = 0;
        if(input = IsInMean(MEANS,*temp))
        {
            entemp = input->enword;
            if(strcmp(entemp[0]->word,new_e->word) > 0)
                //entemp + 1 = (Entry**)realloc(entemp,sizeof(entemp) + sizeof(Entry*));  "expression must be modifiable lvalue"
            while(entemp + index)
            {
                if((cmp = strcmp((entemp[index])->word,new_e->word)) < 0 && strcmp((entemp[index + 1])->word,new_e->word) > 0)
                {
                    //(entemp + index + 1) = (Entry**)realloc(entemp + index,sizeof(entemp + index) + sizeof(Entry*));  "expression must be modifiable lvalue"
                    //if(!(entemp + index + 1))
                    //  Pexit(STANDARD_C);
                }
                else if(cmp <0)
                {
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            input = FindMeanPlace(MEANS,*temp);
            mtemp  = input->next;
            input->next = NewMean(STANDARD_C,new_e,*temp);
        }
    }
}
```

STANDARD_INPUT is defined as the master dictionary (the first Entry*), the yearly dictionary (first Year*) and the meanings dictionary (first Meaning*). STANDARD_C is defined as the names of the variables from the standard input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to do (per comments) is enlarge the dope vector `entemp` itself, but add the new space to the *beginning* instead of the end, you cannot do that with a single operation.  `realloc` must always be passed an *un-offset* pointer received from `malloc` (or `calloc` or a previous call to `realloc`), and it always adds the space at the end.  You have to slide everything down yourself, using `memmove`. For instance:

```
nelements += 1;
entemp = realloc(entemp, nelements * sizeof(Entry *));
assert(entemp);
memmove(entemp, entemp+1, (nelements - 1) * sizeof(Entry *));
```

Also, as I just noticed this: `sizeof(entemp)` **does not** return the allocation size of the memory block pointed to by `entemp`.  It returns the size of *the pointer itself*.  There is no way to retrieve the allocation size of blocks on the C heap; you have to track them yourself.  This is what my `nelements` variable is doing, above.

Closely related obligatory tangential comment: don't cast the return value of `realloc`, just like you don't cast the return value of `malloc` or `calloc`.  This is not just a style thing: casting when you don't need to can hide bugs!

Less closely related but still obligatory style nitpick: `NAMES_IN_ALL_CAPS` are, by longstanding convention, reserved for *constants*.  Do not use them for variable names.  And your magic macros that expand to entire variable / argument declarations are Right Out.

Comment: Actually, I do want `entemp + 1` - I want to increase the amount of space it leads to by one Entry* pointer and shift the pointers one space to the "right". It's a lopsided attempt to order things. 
If you have any suggestions how to do it differently/correctly, please say so - I am not the most proficient of people. @casting - I'm afraid I am forced to do that, since it's the demands of the course teachers.

Comment: Ah.  You can't do that with `realloc` by itself.  See edit which will occur shortly.